# Is there anyway to switch off the switch application warning from inside a uwp webview

Tags: windows, webview, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have an app that opens other part of the app inside the webview, but I need to turn off the warning of switching apps. The idea is to the user to just open another part of the app when he clicks the page inside the webview. Anyone has any thoughts?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Handle the UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified event.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks, it really worked